# sails-generate-reactjs by erikschlegel

Tags: reactjs, sails.js

I have followed the directions here: https://github.com/erikschlegel/sails-generate-reactjs , however when i try to:

```
sails new <%-yourReactAppName> --force
```

I get:

```
-bash: %-myApp: No such file or directory
```

I have tried sudo reinstalling but I just can get past this. Can anyone give me any ideas? I also tried sudo. Nothing works.

Any ideas or help is appreciated

Comment: I'd try the substitution `<%-yourReactAppName>` => `myApp` instead of just replacing `yourReactAppName`. So the command would look like `sails new myApp --force`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should not have `%-` in your App name. You probably want to do this instead

```
sails new myApp --force
```